# Powershell Make a function for directories and add a prefix at the end

Tags: function, powershell, directory, prefix

Make a function that makes 3 directories with the name John_S and add the prefix and appended with the number 1, 2, m
Example
1.  John_S1
2.  John_S2
3.  John_S3
Use a loop  (ForEach)
Use a variable for the number of iterations
What I have so far...

```
$DirName = "John_S"
function mulcheck {New-item "$DirName"}
    $i = 1
    foreach($DirName in $DirNames)
{$newname = $DirName Rename-Item $($DirName) $newname $i++}
```

Comment: hi, were you intending to loop a variable number of times like  `for ($i=1; $i -le $count; $i++) {...}`

Comment: HI, Im trying to make a function that every time i run it, it will create a directory name "John_S" and each time I run the the same function, if there's already a directory name "John_S" it will make another same name directory with a Prefix number to it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate the numbers 1 through 3 is with the `..` range operator:

```
foreach($suffix in 1..3){
  mkdir "John_S${suffix}"
}
```

To make the function re-usable with something other than `John_S`, declare a `[string]` parameter for the prefix:

```
function New-Directories([string]$Prefix) {
  foreach($suffix in 1..3){
    mkdir "${Prefix}${suffix}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi this is awesome, but this only allows me to use the function once in each directories. Is it possible to make a function that creates 1 directory at a time with increments in prefix?

Comment: look at your function, is there to make the suffix paramter be declared while John_S stays the same?

Comment: @Jeffrie sure, but I thought you wanted to have the function create 3 different folders? So do want to accept 3 distinct suffixes at a time, or...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your latest comment correctly, you want a function that takes the name of a new folder and checks if a folder with that name altready exists in the rootpath.  When that is the case, it should create a new folder with the given name, but with an index number appended to it, so it has a unique name.

For that you can use something like this:

```
function New-Folder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$RootPath = $pwd,  # use the current working directory as default

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$FolderName
    )
    # get an array of all directory names (name only) of the folders with a similar name already present
    $folders = @((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter "$FolderName*" -Directory).Name)
    $NewName = $FolderName
    if ($folders.Count) {
        $count = 1
        while ($folders -contains $NewName) {
            # append a number to the FolderName
            $NewName = "{0}{1}" -f $FolderName, $count++
        }
    }
    # we now have a unique foldername, so create the new folder
    $null = New-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $RootPath -ChildPath $NewName) -ItemType Directory
}

New-Folder -FolderName "John_S"
```

If you run this several times, you will have created several folders like

[image]